# Is there a way to assign a value to data.table columns selected programmatically by row?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm working on a data table with roughly 500 columns and several thousands of rows, with each column representing an item that may or may not appear in a string. For example, my data looks something like this

```
   String                Item 1 Item 2  Item 3 Item 4
1  "Item 1Item 2Item 4"    0     0        0     0
2  "Item 1Item 2"          0     0        0     0      
3  "Item 3"                0     0        0     0
```

I have parsed the string into the item numbers and the resulting items are in a list (so list item 1 would have elements "Item 1" "Item 2" and "Item 4" for the first observation above.

I'm attempting to change the value of each column programmatically by using each item of the list as the column names for the row, and then assigning a 1 to those columns. For example, I can construct a simple for loop that does what I'm looking for:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
   data[i, eval(unlist(listofitems[[i]])) := 1]
}
```

which returns

```
  String                Item 1 Item 2  Item 3 Item 4
1  "Item 1Item 2Item 4"    1     1        0     1
2  "Item 1Item 2"          1     1        0     0      
3  "Item 3"                0     0        1     0
```

However, given the size of the data and how often similar situations arise (times when I would like to be able to do a row-wise operation on a data table to columns assigned by reference), I was hoping there might be a more "data.table-y" way to get to the final answer.

Comment: is the space between item and the number intentional or a typo?

Comment: The spacing, and the delimiters, are inconsistent. However, they have already been parsed into the list I mentioned in the question. I've edited the question to be more consistent with the formatting of the actual data.

Comment: can you kindly `dput` the dataset after your parsing?

Comment: A sample of the data from dput-ing the list would be "c("Item 7.01", "Item 9.01"), c("Item 7.01", "Item 9.01"), c("Item 2.02", "Item 9.01"), "Item 1.01", c("Item 2.02", 
    "Item 9.01") where each vector is an element in the list.

Comment: I guess you changed the input data format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to assign using matrix numeric indexing:

```
cols <- setdiff(names(DT), c("String", "ParsedString"))
DT[, (cols) := {
    m <- cbind(rep(1L:.N, lengths(ParsedString)), 
        match(unlist(ParsedString), names(.SD)))
    ans <- as.matrix(.SD)
    ans[m] <- 1L
    as.data.table(ans)
}, .SDcols=cols]
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread('String,Item 1,Item 2,Item 3,Item 4
"Item 1:Item 2:Item 4",0,0,0,0
"Item 1:Item 2",0,0,0,0      
"Item 3",0,0,0,0')
DT[, ParsedString := strsplit(String, split=":")]
```

Comment: That's a really useful solution (generalizes nicely to other problems I've encountered) and runs very quickly on my data. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

We can use `cSplit_e`

```
library(splitstackshape)
out <- cSplit_e(data[1], 'String', type = 'character', sep=":", fill = 0)
names(out)[-1] <- sub("String_", "", names(out)[-1])
out
#              String Item 1 Item 3 Item2 Item4
#1 Item 1:Item2:Item4      1      0     1     1
#2       Item 1:Item2      1      0     1     0
#3             Item 3      0      1     0     0
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(String = c("Item 1:Item2:Item4", "Item 1:Item2", 
"Item 3"), Item1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), Item2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), Item3 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L), Item4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3"))
```

Comment: Thanks for this! The format of the string isn't quite so clean, but I can see how, if I just do some work to clean the string, this would make the whole exercise really simple.

Comment: @JerryMathis It is very easy to change the column names `out <- cSplit_e(data[1], 'String', type = 'character', sep=":", fill = 0); names(out)[-1] <- sub("String_", "", names(out)[-1])`

Comment: The issue is that the strings aren't uniform throughout the data. A lot of it was hand coded, another part was generated by machine, etc. so it's hard to say the delimiter is a particular character or pattern. That's why I was operating off of the already-parsed list of column names. I realize that wasn't really discernible from the original post - my apologies!